# Testeando con Minitest en Rails, cómo evaluar la llamada a un mètodo en si y no lo que este retornaría?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, test

Estoy escribiendo un test para un helper que dependiendo del tipo de objeto que le pase, llama a un método u otro para ir construyendo un `span`.

Este es el helper que estoy testeando:

```
  def label_for(object)
    status = object&.status
    label_type =
      case object.class.name
      when "Subscription"
        class_for_subscription_status(status)
      when "Payment"
        class_for_payment_status(status)
      end
    content_tag(:span, status, class: "label #{label_type}")
  end
```

Lo que necesito evaluar es la llamada a `class_for_subscription_status(status)` dentro del `case` statement y no lo que este método retornaría (que es un simple `String`).

Este es el test que tengo hasta ahora, pero que compara el `String` que está devolviendo la llamada a `class_for_subscription_status(status)` contra el objeto `span` construído por el helper, lo cual no es el comportamiento deseado:

```
  test "#label_for(object) should invoke the right helper if object is of class Subscription" do
    AuxiliariesHelperTest.any_instance.stubs(:class_for_subscription_status)
      .with(subscriptions(:user).status).returns(class_for_subscription_status((subscriptions(:user).status)))

    assert_equal class_for_subscription_status(subscriptions(:user).status), label_for(subscriptions(:user))
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sea, en el fondo necesitas testear que estás entrando a la condición del `case` correcta y no lo que te retorne ¿es eso?.
Para tal caso, podrías hacer algo con [minitest-expects](https://github.com/bhenderson/minitest-expects) como:

```
AuxiliariesHelperTest.any_instance.expects(:class_for_subscription_status).once
label_for(subscriptions(:user))
```